# Two owned stripe accounts on an app (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I know there are similar questions to this one, but I haven't found a clear answer.
I have an ecommerce that charges to two different stripe accounts (different owners). However, this two accounts are "controlled". This means that I don't have to create charges on behalf of multiple accounts. I'd rather make direct charges to these two accounts.

Knowing this: do I have to set up Stripe Connect? Or can I manage multiple keys for the different accounts?
In case I have to use Stripe Connect, how can I create the account so it's hardcoded?

Comment: Simply use the API keys for the correct account in the code depending on where you want the API request(s) to go

Comment: So, basically I just set Stripe.api_key = key_of_the_ecommerce before I make the charge?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication shows how to set the API key on a per request basis. However doing oauth and using the stripe-account header (so Connect and charging directly) would be preferred from a security standpoint.